# Automatically changing traces in Altium from impedance layer stackup

Tags: pcb-design, altium, impedance-matching

Altium has the ability to track impedance in the layer stack manager. Is there a way to have it automatically update the trace sizes of controlled impedance traces such as diff pairs if the stackup or Dk changes?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the stack-up will affect the calculated trace width for impedance-controlled  traces; however it will not automatically update existing traces.

To update trace width, select the traces of interest and use the "**Route > Retrace Selected**" command. This is assuming that you have a Design Rule in place which links the impedance profile to a net class. For more information see "[Interactively Routing with Controlled Impedances on a PCB in Altium Designer: Routing Width Design Rule](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/interactively-routing-controlled-impedance-pcb#!routing-width-design-rule)" in the official documentation.

To automatically select all traces that belong to a specific impedance profile, you can select Nets in the the PCB Panel and click the appropriate net class.

[image: Net class selection in PCB panel]